# Need to display Inputs one at a time using For Loop

Tags: php, html

Guys I just needed to display inputs one by one each time the user click the submit. The problem on using php is that when you use loop, it display all at one time. Please Help guys.

Output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxVLn.png)

This is my code

```php
<?php
for($c=1;$c<=10;$c++){
  echo '<form method="POST" class="form-anticlear"> 
  Enter Number :  
  <input type="number" name="num[$c]" required />    
  <input  type="SUBMIT" name="button" value="Submit" required> 
  </form>';
 }

?>
```

Comment: " it display all at one time." - as you count from 1 to 10 in each case, without checking any other condition. What should be the expected behaviour?

Comment: is there any way to display it one at a time?

Comment: "one at a time" - what does that mean? Exactly one? Then remove the loop. One in the first step, two in the second, and so on - then use a hidden form field to control the loop condition

Comment: yeah, but i didn't know how to do it sir. sorry...

Comment: To do what? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: I am guessing you want to capture 10 things, one at a time, then submit to the backend? ... If so, this should be done in a client-side script (i.e. Javascript) rather than PHP (backend).

Comment: This would probably be a lot easier using Javascript, unless you have a specific reason to use PHP. But you could record the current count number in the session, or in a hidden field as mentioned above, and then use that each time a value is submitted, to know how many input fields to echo the next time.

Comment: This is the challenge to me of my professor. He cannot also solve this and pass the problem to his students.

Comment: Yeah. I can do it using java or c++. but on php? this is impossible

Comment: If you need to do it in PHP, yeah as ADyson suggests, use a session, record the submitted items, retrieve and display after submission as you go, when you get to the 10th item, you would submit with something (possibly a hidden field) to indicate it was the last item so you know it was the last item and process the values as desired.

Comment: `this is impossible`...it's not, it's just more complicated - but not because of PHP primarily, more because of the stateless client-server architecture of a HTTP-based web application. You need to understand the lifecycle of such applications and then the solution starts to become a lot clearer. If you did this with PHP command-line it wouldn't be too hard...I assume when you're talking about Java and C++ versions you're talking about command-line or desktop GUI apps.

Comment: `He cannot also solve this`...you really believe that? If that's true, then he certainly doesn't merit the title of "professor" in my humble opinion...but it's more likely he just set you a homework task.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't really clear as too what it is you are trying to accomplish. Assuming you want to show another input field every time submit is called, the code below will give you that. The file is called test.php change the `action="test.php"` if your file is called something different.

```php
<?php

$total = 1;
if (isset($_POST["background-number"])) {
    $total += $_POST["background-number"];
}

for ($c = 1; $c <= $total; $c++) { ?>
    <form method="POST" class="form-anticlear" action="test.php">
        Enter Number :
        <input type="hidden" name="background-number" value="<?= $total ?>"/>
        <input type="number" name="number-input" required/>
        <input type="SUBMIT" name="button" value="Submit" required>
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```